# index.php appears as query string in htaccess redirect

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I need to redirect from one directory to other keeping query string with .htaccess as I have changed search directory from `/global/search/` to `/search/`

Redirect

```
localhost/site/global/search/index.php?keyword=hi&search=all
```

To

```
localhost/site/search/?keyword=hi&search=all
```

Directory structure

```
wamp/www/site/global/search/index.php   //for /global/ directory
wamp/www/site/search/index.php          //for /search/ directory
```

I am trying this way

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^global/search(/?|/index.php?)$ /site/search/?$1 [QSA,R=301,L]
```

This is working except I am getting `index.php` in query string

I am getting this url after redirect.

```
http://localhost/site/search/?/index.php&keyword=hi&search=all
```

I want this url to be like

```
http://localhost/site/search/?keyword=hi&search=all
```

Please see why index.php is coming in redirected url as query string and suggest way to get clean query string without index.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try this rule:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^global/search(/?|/index\.php)$ /site/search/ [NC,R=301,L]
```

Comment: I am getting same result with `RewriteRule ^global/search(/?|/index\.php) /site/search/ [QSA,R=301,L]` do I need to keep `$` and `NC` insted of `QSA` in rule.

Comment: QSA is not needed if you're not modifying query string. NC is for ignore case. It is better to keep `$` in the end.